# How to Overlay a live updating object on live Screen in real-time?

Tags: python, graph, statistics, live

Here I'm having a Video's short gif[image: A.I. learns to drive on a pipe]

In this gif, you can see that an A.I. is driving on a Pipe, but there also you can see some stats in real-time. I want to do the same but don't know how to do it? Can somebody help me out with this
But I don't want to do exact same but to display some different live stats in real-time as I work on my PC,
**Please use Python 3.9+ to do so**

For the actual full video link click [here](https://www.youtube.com/embed/iZIPowqm-fo?start=1140)